# Trouble installing python selenium package on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am new to python. I am using VS code on Windows. Following is my simple python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

I am trying to install selenium package but it is giving me error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'.
I tried following commands.

```
conda install selenium
python -m pip install -U selenium
```

Then I tried in a virtual env

```
conda create -n selenium-env python=3.6
conda activate selenium-env
conda install -n selenium0env selenium
```

Still getting the same error.
**Update:**

I noticed that when I first run the py file after restarting VS code, it activates one of my virtual environments automatically. I think that virtual env does not have selenium installed in it. Below is the terminal output when I run the py file

How do I stop that environment from getting activated automatically? I want to run this in a different environment.

```
PS D:\Learnings\Python\SampleDesktopApp> conda activate pyfinance

PS D:\Learnings\Python\SampleDesktopApp> & 

C:/Users/rajen/anaconda3/envs/pyfinance/python.exe 
d:/Learnings/Python/SampleDesktopApp/Test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "d:\Learnings\Python\SampleDesktopApp\Test.py", line 1, in <module>

    from selenium import webdriver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

PS D:\Learnings\Python\SampleDesktopApp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was installing the selenium in one environment and running py file in another. So I used VS code option Python: Select Interpreter to change the environment while running the file. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well first things first update your pip.

Use the command: ***python -m pip install --upgrade pip***
if that doesn't work then there is a chance there's a bug in your Python or site-packages directory. Uninstall Python and then reinstall the latest version and it should work then.

*Side note*: Once you get selenium working, you can't just initialize Firefox or Chrome without having their respective drivers.
for Firefox its geckodriver.exe https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
for Chrome its chromedriver.exe https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Once you have the driver installed you have to include the driver in the Webdriver argument executable_path like so:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="drivers/geckodriver.exe")
```

**Update**

Conda is automatically running the virutalenv so instead of using command *conda activate pyfinance*.

try running with just simple: *python pyfinance.py*

Comment: Upgrade did not help. Thanks for info on setting up driver. I am going to do that. But I need to get rid of package issue first. I have updated the question. Please guide me if you can before I uninstall the python